# Programming language lexer in Rust

Tags: rust, compiler

I'm working through [Crafting Interpreters](http://craftinginterpreters.com/) and trying to apply what I've learned in Rust. I've got the lexer working in what feels like a reasonably idiomatic way (hooray!), but I have a feeling it could be simplified.

The main part I'm unsure about is the code for reading strings, numbers and identifiers - it feels too complex, but I wasn't able to figure out a better way of doing it.

Any other feedback would be appreciated! The full code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/17cupsofcoffee/ein), but there's not much there other than the lexer yet.

```
pub mod tokens;

use std::str::CharIndices;
use self::tokens::Token;

#[inline]
fn is_id_start(ch: char) -> bool {
    ch == '_' || ch.is_ascii_alphabetic()
}

#[inline]
fn is_id_continue(ch: char) -> bool {
    ch == '_' || ch.is_ascii_digit()
}

pub type Location = usize;

#[derive(Debug, Fail, PartialEq)]
pub enum LexicalError {
    #[fail(display = "Invalid character '{}' found at {}", ch, location)]
    InvalidCharacter { ch: char, location: Location },

    #[fail(display = "String starting at {} was not terminated", location)]
    UnterminatedString { location: Location },
}

pub type SpanResult<'input> = Result<(Location, Token<'input>, Location), LexicalError>;

pub struct Lexer<'input> {
    source: &'input str,
    chars: CharIndices<'input>,
    lookahead: Option<(usize, char)>,
    lookahead2: Option<(usize, char)>,
}

impl<'input> Lexer<'input> {
    pub fn new(source: &'input str) -> Lexer<'input> {
        let mut chars = source.char_indices();
        let lookahead = chars.next();
        let lookahead2 = chars.next();

        Lexer {
            source,
            chars,
            lookahead,
            lookahead2,
        }
    }

    fn bump(&mut self) -> Option<(usize, char)> {
        let next = self.lookahead;
        self.lookahead = self.lookahead2;
        self.lookahead2 = self.chars.next();
        next
    }

    fn take_until<F>(&mut self, mut terminate: F) -> Option<usize>
    where
        F: FnMut(char) -> bool,
    {
        while let Some((i, ch)) = self.lookahead {
            if terminate(ch) {
                return Some(i);
            } else {
                self.bump();
            }
        }

        None
    }

    fn take_while<F>(&mut self, mut condition: F) -> Option<usize>
    where
        F: FnMut(char) -> bool,
    {
        self.take_until(|ch| !condition(ch))
    }

    fn skip_to_line_end(&mut self) {
        self.take_while(|ch| ch != '\n');
    }

    fn skip_whitespace(&mut self) {
        self.take_while(|ch| ch.is_whitespace());
    }

    fn read_string(&mut self, pos: usize) -> SpanResult<'input> {
        match self.take_until(|ch| ch == '"') {
            Some(i) => {
                self.bump();
                Ok((pos, Token::String(&self.source[pos + 1..i]), i + 1))
            }
            None => Err(LexicalError::UnterminatedString { location: pos }),
        }
    }

    fn read_number(&mut self, pos: usize) -> SpanResult<'input> {
        let mut end = self.take_while(|ch| ch.is_ascii_digit());

        if let Some((_, '.')) = self.lookahead {
            // Check if it's a decimal or a field access
            if let Some((_, next_ch)) = self.lookahead2 {
                if next_ch.is_ascii_digit() {
                    self.bump();
                    end = self.take_while(|ch| ch.is_ascii_digit());
                }
            }
        }

        let end = end.unwrap_or_else(|| self.source.len());

        Ok((
            pos,
            Token::Number(self.source[pos..end].parse().expect("unparsable number")),
            end,
        ))
    }

    fn read_identifier(&mut self, pos: usize) -> SpanResult<'input> {
        let end = self.take_while(|ch| is_id_start(ch) || is_id_continue(ch))
            .unwrap_or_else(|| self.source.len());

        match &self.source[pos..end] {
            "else" => Ok((pos, Token::Else, end)),
            "false" => Ok((pos, Token::False, end)),
            "fn" => Ok((pos, Token::Fn, end)),
            "for" => Ok((pos, Token::For, end)),
            "if" => Ok((pos, Token::If, end)),
            "nil" => Ok((pos, Token::Nil, end)),
            "print" => Ok((pos, Token::Print, end)),
            "return" => Ok((pos, Token::Return, end)),
            "this" => Ok((pos, Token::This, end)),
            "true" => Ok((pos, Token::True, end)),
            "let" => Ok((pos, Token::Let, end)),
            "while" => Ok((pos, Token::While, end)),
            id => Ok((pos, Token::Identifier(id), end)),
        }
    }
}

impl<'input> Iterator for Lexer<'input> {
    type Item = SpanResult<'input>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<SpanResult<'input>> {
        self.skip_whitespace();

        if let Some((i, ch)) = self.bump() {
            match ch {
                '{' => Some(Ok((i, Token::OpenBrace, i + 1))),
                '}' => Some(Ok((i, Token::CloseBrace, i + 1))),
                '(' => Some(Ok((i, Token::OpenParen, i + 1))),
                ')' => Some(Ok((i, Token::CloseParen, i + 1))),
                '[' => Some(Ok((i, Token::OpenBracket, i + 1))),
                ']' => Some(Ok((i, Token::CloseBracket, i + 1))),
                ';' => Some(Ok((i, Token::Semicolon, i + 1))),
                ',' => Some(Ok((i, Token::Comma, i + 1))),
                '.' => Some(Ok((i, Token::Dot, i + 1))),
                '+' => Some(Ok((i, Token::Plus, i + 1))),
                '-' => Some(Ok((i, Token::Minus, i + 1))),
                '*' => Some(Ok((i, Token::Star, i + 1))),

                '/' => {
                    if let Some((_, '/')) = self.lookahead {
                        self.skip_to_line_end();
                        self.next()
                    } else {
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::Slash, i + 1)))
                    }
                }

                '!' => {
                    if let Some((_, '=')) = self.lookahead {
                        self.bump();
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::NotEqual, i + 2)))
                    } else {
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::Not, i + 1)))
                    }
                }

                '=' => {
                    if let Some((_, '=')) = self.lookahead {
                        self.bump();
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::EqualEqual, i + 2)))
                    } else {
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::Equal, i + 1)))
                    }
                }

                '>' => {
                    if let Some((_, '=')) = self.lookahead {
                        self.bump();
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::GreaterEqual, i + 2)))
                    } else {
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::Greater, i + 1)))
                    }
                }

                '<' => {
                    if let Some((_, '=')) = self.lookahead {
                        self.bump();
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::LessEqual, i + 2)))
                    } else {
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::Less, i + 1)))
                    }
                }

                '&' => {
                    if let Some((_, '&')) = self.lookahead {
                        self.bump();
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::AmpAmp, i + 2)))
                    } else {
                        Some(Err(LexicalError::InvalidCharacter { ch, location: i }))
                    }
                }

                '|' => {
                    if let Some((_, '|')) = self.lookahead {
                        self.bump();
                        Some(Ok((i, Token::PipePipe, i + 2)))
                    } else {
                        Some(Err(LexicalError::InvalidCharacter { ch, location: i }))
                    }
                }

                '"' => Some(self.read_string(i)),
                ch if is_id_start(ch) => Some(self.read_identifier(i)),
                ch if ch.is_ascii_digit() => Some(self.read_number(i)),

                ch => Some(Err(LexicalError::InvalidCharacter { ch, location: i })),
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's frowned upon if there's already an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful about [calling `next` multiple times without checking the result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next). Emphasis mine:

> Returns `None` when iteration is finished. *Individual iterator implementations may choose to resume iteration, and so calling `next()` again may or may not eventually start returning `Some(Item)` again at some point*.

It's safest to use [`fuse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse).

I recommend using associated types in trait implementations. This keeps the code DRYer and oftentimes shorter:

```
// Use this
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self> {
// Instead of
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<SpanResult<'input>> {
```

Your implementation of `is_id_continue` is suspicious. Most of the time, the "continuation" character is a superset of the initial character. I'd have expected something like

```
fn is_id_continue(ch: char) -> bool {
    is_id_start() || ch.is_ascii_digit()
}
```

I'm not a fan of the lack of symmetry in these two arms:

```
ch if is_id_start(ch) => Some(self.read_identifier(i)),
ch if ch.is_ascii_digit() => Some(self.read_number(i)),
// Would rather
ch if is_number_start(ch) => Some(self.read_number(i)),
```

In all of my tokenizers, I've gotten away from the concept of "byte" or "char" for all but the lowest level of manipulation. This could come in useful here because you could phrase the code as "does the input stream start with `>=`? Does it start with `>`?" This would simplify that particular bit.

You might also be able to DRY up your two-char token parsing into a method.

The `match` in `read_identifier` cannot fail, so you could move the `Ok` outside of it to reduce the duplication.

Comment: That's all really helpful feedback, thank you!